# No efi system partition was found when trying to install ubuntu next to windows 10

Tags: uefi, grub-efi

I have windows 10 on disk 0 (Only one partition on the SSD Drive), and I have 2 partitions on disk 1, I'm trying to install ubuntu 20.04 on the first partition of disk 1, I was ready to format and install ubuntu there but I got the no efi system partition and got scared, I don't understand much about what I should do, create an efi partition? change something on my motherboard bios? also I don't know in what partition should I install grub? any help is appreciated my dudes

[My motherboard is on legacy+uefi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtSw6.jpg)

[This is where I want to install ubuntu, second hard drive, first partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljtMx.jpg)

[Diskpart list disk shows me that the first two drives are not in Gpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHou5.jpg)

[The disk 0 and 1 are actually in MBR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khI2p.jpg)

[These are the settings I used in rufus to create a live boootable ubuntu pendrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQLyf.jpg)

[Error I get (not mine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1fKV.jpg)

Comment: Did you install Windows 10 as-is , or was it upgraded from a prior release?  Because you might not have an EFI partition if you upgraded from an older version of Windows and would need to use the legacy BIOS option.  As far as installation of Ubuntu to a NTFS partition - that's not going to work -- you should remove this partition and make free, unpartitioned space available for the Ubuntu installer.  I strongly suggest DO NOT use Windows to manage partitions for Ubuntu-- you can use the "Disks" application in the live session: "Try Ubuntu" from installation media

Comment: You won't have an EFI partition if running Win 10 in Legacy BIOS. Thr first thing to do is convert your Win 10 disk 0 [from MBR to GPT](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-move-bios-uefi-windows-10) and then in your BIOS switch from Legacy to UEFI. Do the same for disk 1.

Comment: @Nmath I don't remember, I think I upgraded, I don't think I have an EFI partition, is there a way to find out? Don't worry about the NTFS partition, during installation I use ubuntu to delete that NTFS partition, and create the swap and the ext4 partition for ubuntu.

Comment: If you have an EFI partition, there will be a partition containing a folder "EFI" and in that folder there will be another folder called "Microsoft" if Windows uses EFI.

Comment: @PaulBenson If I understand, I should first convert the disk 0 and disk 1 from MBR to GPT following your tutorial, is it safe? and then switch from legacy+uefi to uefi in my motherboard? I'll try that and get back

Comment: Does [this link] (https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-alongside-windows-10-dual-boot) help? If not, we have to first partition your hard drive correctly

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS, is then how it boots once installed. To boot install media you choose in UEFI's one time boot menu often f12, but varies by vendor. But boot once installed is defined by setting(s) in UEFI for UEFI or Legacy/BIOS/CSM. Windows only boots from MBR partitioned drives with BIOS and Windows only boots from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI. Ubuntu will let you boot in UEFI mode from MBR, but should not. Post this in your question: `sudo parted -l` to see partition type & partitions.

Comment: Your Windows is installed to boot BIOS, you want to install Ubuntu to also Boot BIOS. This is so the GRUB boot loader will boot either. On Windows, “System Information” in Start panel and under BIOS Mode, you can find the boot mode. If it says Legacy, your system has BIOS. If it says UEFI, well it’s UEFI.

Comment: @Danilux The method to convert your disks should be safe and is unique to Win10 in that it doesn't wipe your disk. Before that you could not convert to GPT easily without wiping your disk. Even so, I'd back-up your data first, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @PaulBenson I used mbr2gpt to convert disk 0 (windows), but I had to use easyus partition manager to convert disk 1 (because mbr2gpt only converts system disks), but it worked great, I switched from legacy to uefi, and I installed ubuntu with no problem, made an efi,swap and / partition, grub is running smoothly, thanks mate

Comment: @Danilux You're welcome. I was going to suggest using [DiskPart](https://www.diskpart.com/articles/convert-ssd-to-gpt-command-prompt-7201.html) which is a great little tool that comes with Windows for your empty disk 1. It would have saved you the trouble of installing *EaseUs*. But *EaseUs* is fine too if a bit more work. Good to see it all went smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need an EFI System partition for installing ubuntu. And only root file system creation is enough. Click on the partition where you want to install ubuntu  and delete partition. Next again click the unallocated space and click the + button. Then select ext4 as the file system and set mount point to / (filesystem root). Tyen click the partition type as Primary. Then create the partition. Now click the new root partition and click Next to install ubuntu there.

Hope that helps

Comment: If you have a UEFI computer it's rather stupid not to use it as a UEFI computer and stick to an antiquated MBR boot-up instead. In addition **if dual-booting**, it's well advised that you do convert to GPT and run on UEFI, otherwise this can cause issues as so many users have already found this out from posting here.

Comment: even if you can switch between uefi/legacy in BIOS, if you have windows installed in legacy, you must install ubuntu also in legacy (no EFI partition) otherwise it will not boot; if windows was installed in legacy, and then linux installed with efi partition and it does not boot, delete efi partition and reinstall linux